Characterizing "inward" and "outward" sets
This question arises from reading papers by Halpern (1970) and Lee and Tan (1978).
Let $E$ be a real Hausdorff topological vector space and $K$ be a non-empty convex subset of $E.$ For each $x \in K,$ define
$$I_k(x) =\{x+\lambda(y-x): y \in K, \lambda > 0 \}$$
and
$$O_k(x) =\{x+\lambda(y-x): y \in K, \lambda < 0 \}.$$
These sets are known as the inward set and outward set of $x$ with respect to $K,$ respectively.
Suppose $f: K \rightarrow E$ is a set-valued function and $f(x)$ is a non-empty closed convex subset of $E.$ Then $f$ is said to be weakly inward on $K$ (respectively, weakly outward on $K$) if for each $x \in K, f(x) \cap \textrm{cl} (I_k(x)) \neq \emptyset$ (respectively, $f(x) \cap \textrm{cl} (O_k(x) \neq \emptyset$).
How should I think about $\textrm{cl} (I_k(x))$? Under what conditions is it true that $\textrm{cl} (I_k(x)) = \{x+\lambda(y-x): y \in K, \lambda \geq 0 \}$?
I am struggling to get intuition on what $\textrm{cl} (I_k(x))$ means "really." Thanks!

Are you sure they are not using $\partial K$?

@julio_es_sui_glace, I don't think they are.

Do you mean $f : K \to \mathscr P(E)$ (power set of $E$)? As currently stated, the values of $f$ are elements of $E$, not sets. $I_k(x)$ is the cone consisting of all rays eminating from $x$ and passing through some element of $K$. $O_k(x)$ is the opposing cone (the union of the opposite rays from those making up $I_k(x)$. But $x$ is removed from both cones. However, $x$ is not is excluded from either cone, so neither is closed. $\text{cl}(I_k(x))$ adds in $x$ and the rays tangent to $K$ (passing though $\partial K$, but not $K$ itself). It equals the indicated set when $K$ is closed.

But it can also equal the indicated set when $K$ is not closed. For example, consider $K$ to be an open disk in the plane and $x$ is some exterior point. $I_k(x)$ consists of an infinite sector at $x$ extending between the two tangents to the disk passing through $x$. Only the two points of tangency need to be added to $K$ to make $\textrm{cl} (I_k(x)) = {x+\lambda(y-x): y \in K, \lambda \geq 0 }$

@PaulSinclair, thank you! Yes, I mean $f: K \rightarrow \mathscr{P}(E).$ How would I go about proving that $\textrm{cl} (I_k(x)) = {x+\lambda(y-x): y \in K, \lambda \geq 0 }$ is true whenever $K$ is closed? I had suspected that was true for a while, but I tried a standard argument using sequences and that doesn't appear to lead anywhere. Some guidance would be appreciated. :)
